# Rotational error

Tags: linear-algebra

In a paper ("Non-linear complementary filters on the special orthogonal group",  [Mahony](https://hal-univ-tlse3.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00488376/document)), there mentioned about Rotational Error term.

$Pa(R)=\frac{1}{2}(R−R^T)$

But, as I know, rotational error is from logarithm,

$log(R) = \frac{\theta}{2sin\theta}(R-R^T)$, $cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}(tr(R)-1)$

What's the difference between them?

And one more question in same paper, 
rotational error between two vectors mentioned as,

$v\times v'$

But, norm of cross product is $|v||v'|sin\theta$ so, it decreased when $\theta$ is over $\pi/2$. Is that reasonable for error term?